# regular expression lookbehind in EMeditor

Tags: regex

In EMeditor I tried to grab string with regular expression lookbehind.

For example, I hope to grab in "Web" in "World Wide Web"

```
W.*?b
```

will grab 1st "World Wide Web" / 2nd "Wide Web" / 3rd "Web" serially.

I hope to grab "Web" first with non-greedy quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with look behinds.

The problem is that your regex will match the first `W` it hits. What you want is this:

```
W\w*b
```

Which will only match word characters. Or even this to match anything not a space:

```
W\S*b
```

Comment: really thanks! one of the good solutions. and I hope to know how to use 'lookbehind' more.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Regex...

```
W\w*$
```

Good Luck!